# Azure Stream Analytics- "Inherit Partitioning" in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-stream-analytics

I am kind of new to Azure Stream Analytics, and right now I am trying to add *Inherit Partitioning* by choosing "*Inherite partition schema of previous query stem or input*"

[image]

To be able to apply this to all environments, I would like to add that to the ARM, Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.streamanalytics/streamingjobs#Microsoft.Sql/Server/Database) source, I should be able to choose 0 for *maxWriterCount*, but after deploy, we still have the first option chosen
[image]

Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a UX bug because you're doing the right thing, which is the same thing as this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/streaming-at-scale/blob/main/eventhubs-streamanalytics-azuresql/stream-analytics-job-arm-template.json) does. I'll get this looked into but you should be okay setting it to 0 in ARM template.